# Error: call revert exception when fetching products from Solidity contract using ethers.js

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I am building a decentralized e-commerce platform (Dappazon) using React and Solidity. In my React app, I'm trying to fetch and display the products stored in the 'items' mapping of the Dappazon contract using ethers.js. However, I am encountering an issue with a "call revert exception" when trying to access the items in the contract.

I am trying to fetch product details from the items mapping in the Dappazon contract using ethers.js in my React application. However, when I use the for loop to fetch items one by one, I encounter the "call revert exception" error. I suspect this might be due to the asynchronous nature of the contract call, but I'm not entirely sure how to resolve it.

Solidity:

```
    struct Item {
        uint256 id;
        string name;
        string category;
        string image;
        uint256 cost;
        uint256 rating;
        uint256 stock;
    }
    mapping(uint256 => Item) public items;
```

React.js - App.js

```
    const dappazon = new ethers.Contract(
      config[network.chainId].dappazon.address,
      Dappazon,
      provider
    );
    console.log(dappazon);
    // console.log(dappazon)
    setDappazon(dappazon);

    const items = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      const item = await dappazon.items(i);
      console.log(item);
      items.push(item);
    }
```

error:

```
index.ts:269 Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception [See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION]
    (method="items(uint256)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:427:1)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (index.ts:400:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)
```

Comment: can you change `var i = 0;` to `let i = 0;`

Comment: It doesn't work either. In fact, it gives me errors even when I tried to access the first element in the mapping without the loop.

Comment: maybe you did not set the `const dappazon = new ethers.Contract(
      config[network.chainId].dappazon.address,
      Dappazon,
      provider
    );` correctly